# DML operation INSERT not allowed on Campaign

Tags: campaign

I am getting below error even I am system Administrator and having CRUD permission on this object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be a Marketing User in order to create campaigns.
Go to profile and check Marketing User checkbox

From the documentation:

> Marketing User When enabled, the user can create, edit, and delete
>   campaigns, configure advanced campaign setup, import leads, and update
>   campaign history via the member import wizards. Available in
>   Professional, Enterprise, and Unlimited Editions.
>
> To use the campaign import wizards, Marketing Users must also have the
>   Marketing User profile (or the “Import Leads” permission and the
>   “Edit” permission on campaigns in Enterprise and Unlimited Edition
>   organizations).
>
> If this option isn’t selected, the user can only view campaigns and
>   advanced campaign setup, edit the Campaign History for a single lead
>   or contact, and run campaign reports.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help.Please mark it as the best answer if this answers your question so that others can benefit from this