# DML operation Insert not allowed on CareProgram

Tags: health-cloud

Based on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162011/dml-operation-insert-not-allowed-on-campaign) it appears that my user might need some type of permission for HealthCloud to create a CareProgram object. Does anybody know what I am missing to create an instance of this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to make sure you have the Health Cloud permission sets assigned to your user. A better way to do is create a Permission Set Group and add the needed Health Cloud permission sets. I believe you need the Heath Cloud and Health Cloud Platform Permission Set License Assignments as well.